# One class Sturm-Liouville differential equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sturm-liouville-theory

Let $\phi_n(x), \psi_n(x)$ be solution Sturm-Liouville differential equation

$$p(x) y''(x) - 2n p'(x)y'(x)+2n(2n+1)y(x)=0$$
$$\phi_{n}(0)=0, \hspace{3mm} \phi'_{n}(0)=1;$$
$$\psi_{n}(0)=1, \hspace{3mm} \psi'_{n}(0)=0;$$
where p(x) is given.

Question: Is the set $\{\phi_n(x),\psi_n(x)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ orthogonal set?

Comment: It's not really a well defined question in this form (orthogonal in what space?), but ignoring that, the answer has to be *no*, for a general $p$.